# BreezeJS navigation properties not being populated despite data being returned from server

Tags: c#, breeze

I just upgraded from BreezeJS 1.1 to 1.4 however "expand" doesn't seem to be working? I can see my expand going to the server:

```
http://localhost:60198/api/Data/App?$filter=Id%20eq%209&$expand=Household%2CHousehold%2FPrimary
```

and I can see the data coming back:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "App.Models.Base.App, App",
    "Id": 9,
    "Number": "ZZZZ",
    "Name": "ZZZZZ",
    "Household": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "App.Models.Base.Household, App",
      "Id": 6,
      "Primary": {
        "$id": "3",
        "$type": "App.Models.Base.Person, App",
        "Id": 9,
        "FirstName": "ZZZZ",
        "MiddleName": "ZZZZ",
        "LastName": "ZZZ",
      }
    },
    "HouseholdId": 6
  }
]
```

but the household property is null when I try an access it. This used to work with 1.1.

```
breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("App")
    .where("id", "==", id)
    .expand("Household, Household.Primary")
```

which if logged as json turns into

```
query {"resourceName":"App","entityType":null,"wherePredicate":{"_filterQueryOp":{"_$typeName":"FilterQueryOp","name":"Equals"},"_propertyOrExpr":"id","_value":9,"_valueIsLiteral":false},"orderByClause":null,"selectClause":null,"skipCount":null,"takeCount":null,"expandClause":{"propertyPaths":["Household","Household.Primary"]},"parameters":{},"inlineCountEnabled":false,"entityManager":null}
```

**Update:** I downgraded to 1.2.5 and it works again. I looked around in the code and it appears like this check here:
https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/breeze.debug.js#L13312
was return false and therefore the entity was not being updated? Who knows I am very new to the breeze codebase.

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Since you've spelunked to that line in the Breeze code base, do you have any idea why `currentRelatedEntity === relatedEntity` in your case? That's why Breeze would bail out and not set the navigation property value.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation properties were not setup correctly.